# Asus XG-C100C 10GBE NIC stating cable is unplugged

Tags: networking, network-adapter

As the question states, Windows 10 states that the cable is unplugged from the NIC when it is not. The on-board NIC detects a connection using the same cable. Already updated/reinstalled driver, checked for windows updates, updated the UEFI-BIOS, and tried a different PCI-E slot. The NIC works just fine in a different computer. Also tried using an Ubuntu install(on a USB Drive) and had the same issue. Not sure what may be going on at this point.

Computer Info:

- OS: Windows 10 Home 1803
- Motherboard: Asus z270-E
- GPU: GTX 1080
- Ram: 16GB Gskill ddr4
- 240GB Samsung 860 Evo M.2
- NIC: Asus XG-c100c